# To select last 5 date in php

Tags: php

I am using

```
$todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
```

To Fetch todays date.

I dont know how to select last 5 date from present date. is there any option notify me how to select last 5 date from present date.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$dates = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$i days"));
}

print_r($dates);
```

Comment: beat me to it... :) Must admit, yours is more elegant, lacks the doc link though

Comment: Hmm, he does indeed seem to be asking for a date range.  I'd mentally filtered that out.

Answer (score 2):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can do this.

```
$five_days_ago = strtotime('-5 days');
$five_days_formatted = date('Y-m-d', $five_days_ago);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tomorrow  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

this should do, if i understood your question correctly:

```
echo strtotime("-5 day");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use function date and strtotime :)

```
$fiveDaysFuture = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));//future
$fiveDaysAgo = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-5 days', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));//ago
```